# How to pass a template variable to a template helper function to preserve context?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I may be using the wrong words to describe my issue so here is the (simplified) code I'm working with.

I'm happy to learn a better way to do this but what I'm currently trying to do is pass `{{assigneeId}}` to the template helper function called `agentIs`. The problem is that I can't find the correct way to pass the value.

```html
<template name="ticket_list">
  {{#each tickets}}
    {{> ticket}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="ticket">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <p>{{assigneeId}}</p>
  {{> ticket_footer}}
</template>

<template name="ticket_footer">
  {{> agent_list}}
</template>

<template name="agent_list">
  <!-- {{assigneeId}} exists here as expected -->
  assigneeId: {{assigneeId}}
  <label for="agent">Agent</label>
  <select id="agent" name="agent">
    {{#each agents}}
      <!-- value passed: "{{assigneeId}}" -->
      <option value="{{_id}}" {{#if agentIs "{{assigneeId}}"}}selected{{/if}}>
        {{profile.name}}
      </option>
      <!-- value passed: undefined -->
      <option value="{{_id}}" {{#if agentIs assigneeId}}selected{{/if}}>
        {{profile.name}}
      </option>
      <!-- value passed: JSON.parse error -->
      <option value="{{_id}}" {{#if agentIs {{assigneeId}}}}selected{{/if}}>
        {{profile.name}}
      </option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

```js
Template.agent_list.agents = function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({"profile.is_agent": true}, {sort: {profile: 1}});
}

Template.agent_list.agentIs = function(assigneeId) {
  return this._id === assigneeId;
};
```

Comment: Why can't you wrap some template call into `with` block helper? Or I didn't get the question.

Comment: @imslavko Please write up an example and add it as an answer. I'm new to Meteor and Handlebars and any feedback on implementation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be :

```
{{#if agentIs ../assigneeId}}selected{{/if}}
```

The {{#each agents}} block helper introduces a new level in the template contexts tree (the new context corresponds to the current agent), this is why you need to "go back" from one level to properly reference the previous context where assigneeId resides.

Comment: I understand exactly what you're saying though that syntax never crossed my mind and I had no idea how to even find it. Does this syntax have an official name?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/ is the templating system. http://docs.meteor.com/#templates - Meteor's documentation.

Comment: Wow, you just blew my mind with the `../` stuff.  Can't tell you how helpful this is going to be when looping though stuff to be able to get access to the parent.  Wish this was documented somewhere in the docs.meteor.com.  If it is I haven't seen it.

Comment: The only occurence I've found in official docs is here : http://docs.meteor.com/#template_parentdata This syntax originated from Handlebars which is the foundation for Spacebars, the Meteor templating system.