# How do I pass template variables in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I couldnt find an answer for this but I've seen it before.

I want to render a template with a varable set from html and have access to it in js as well. Here's a simple example that covers both of these cases.

```
<template name="a">
    {{>b param="hello"}}
</template>

<template name="b">
    {{param}} {{param2}}
</template>

Template.b.param2 = function() {
    if (this.param == "hello") {
        return "world"
    }
}
```

This doesnt seem to work though.

EDIT:
Well that all works apparently. I didnt include the `#each`:

```
<template name="a">
    {{>b param="hello"}}
</template>

<template name="b">
    {{#each something}}
        {{param}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I think thats what's causing the problem. (sorry this example is a little contrived)

Comment: This works for me with meteor `0.8.1.2`. What version are you using?

Comment: I forgot the #each. check out the edit. Thanks

Comment: So I think this might be an issue with Autoform...

Answer (score 0):

So this was king of a bad question but maybe it will save someone some trouble.

For the `#each` issue, the solution is to do `{{../param}}` which I found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936924/how-to-pass-a-template-variable-to-a-template-helper-function-to-preserve-contex).

However, this didnt work for me because I am using Autoform in which case I actually had to do `{{../../param}}`.