# Pass in template variable as value for custom block helper in Meteor Spacebars (or Handlebars)

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

Usually if I want to pass in a template variable, I can use the '../' instead of {{}} (as shown in [How to pass a template variable to a template helper function to preserve context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936924/how-to-pass-a-template-variable-to-a-template-helper-function-to-preserve-contex)).

However, I'm trying to pass in a template variable as part of a value that will be fed through a custom block helper.

As a very simple example, imagine {{name}} is already defined in the template below and I want to pass it through as the title:

```
  {{#Card title= ../name }}
    <div class="map-container">
      Neat name!
    </div>
  {{/Card}}
```

And my custom block helper looks like this:

```
<template name="Card">
  <h1 class="card-title">{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="card-content">
    {{>Template.contentBlock}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you try using Dynamic Template insertion- http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what the difficulty is here.  Can't you just use `{{#Card title=name}}` if `name` is defined in that context?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, unfortunately Template dynamic doesn't include support for block helpers. As for the variable name without quotes, that's what I'd think too, but it returns blank...

Comment: @richsilv I was mistaken, you're correct, I had another bug causing the failure. For future readers, my helper function was overwriting a Deps.Dependency, thus erasing the helper function after the 1st time the function was called.

Comment: @MattK does this work then, with your helper bug fixed?

Comment: Yup, the problem was somewhere else in the code base